# Can I transit in Lisbon on my way to Oslo as a holder of an official Pakistani passport?

Tags: transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, lisbon

I am a Pakistani doctor, having worked with the United Nations in Africa for a year. I have an official (service) passport issued by the government of Pakistan. I intend to visit Norway for about 8 days and I do not require any visa to enter Norway (because of the official Pakistani passport). I will book a flight with TAP from Accra (Ghana) to Oslo (Norway). This flight has a layover in Lisbon of 26 hours.

1. Would I be allowed to leave the airport and visit Lisbon during these 26 hours, or do I have to stay inside the airport for that period?
2. Should I get a visa for this stay in either case, keeping in mind that I don't have any Schengen visa?

Comment: You will pass through Schengen entry controls in Lisbon, and not in Oslo, so you need to find out whether your official passport permits visa-free entry in Portugal.  If not, you'll need a visa.  In either case, you'll be able to leave the airport.

Comment: Thanks Phoog !!!   Portugal  DOES NOT allow Pakistani official passport holder to enter WITH OUT VALID SCHENGEN VISA. its is the main issue,, I have selected Norway for tourism just because I DO NOT require Schengen Visa for Norway,,  so Why should I try to get Visa for Portugal ? Actually I am in such a remote African country (Liberia) that its not possible for me to get a Schengen Visa. Please suggest me some way out.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to get a visa for Portugal or else book a different flight that goes either directly to Norway or by way of a country where you can enter visa free.

Comment: Dear Phoog .  I highly appreciate your kind and helping gesture. Actually there are no such direct flights, all flights have transit either in Paris , London, Lisbon . But there is a flight of same TAP air having only 1 hour transit in Lisbon, So it is possible that I stay in Airport lounge and get board my connecting flight without passing the immigration counter. ? So in that case I may not be requiring visa ??

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work. Because Portugal and Norway are both in the Schengen area, the second flight is an internal Schengen flight. You must therefore enter the Schengen area (that is, pass the immigration counter) in Portugal no matter how long you stay there.

Comment: Thanks dear.    Romania is not a Schengen country. And I can go Romania on my official Pakistani passport with out visa.    So I change my plan, I start from Accra to Bucharest (Romania) then Bucharest to Oslo. But again the route and airline is same, Accra to Bucharist with a transit in Lisbon, So do i need visa for Portugal or not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71012/discussion-between-umer-and-phoog).

Comment: You might not be able to visit Norway with an official passport for noon official purposes.

Comment: Just apply for a Schengen visa, be much easier, you can only go to Norway on an official purpose like @greatone says and you need a Schengen visa for Portugal. https://www.norway.no/en/liberia/services-info/visitors-visa-res-permit/visitors-visa/

Comment: @phoog This has a bounty on it; may I suggest that you post an answer

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a diplomatic passport, you will need to apply for a transit visa. Your immigration status and passport will be checked in Lisbon, as this is your entry into the Schengen zone.

You need to apply at [the Embassy of the Netherlands](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/applying-for-a-short-stay-schengen-visa/ghana):

> The consular department assesses Schengen visa applications and Dutch
>   Caribbean visa applications. The Kingdom of the Netherlands has made
>   representation arrangements for short stay visa applications (thus for
>   a stay of maximum 90 days per 180 days period) with other Schengen
>   countries.
>
> Residents of Ghana travelling to Portugal, Poland, Luxembourg,
>   Austria, France, or Lithuania, can also apply with the Netherlands
>   embassy in Accra, Ghana.
>
> Those wishing to settle in the aforementioned countries and wishing to
>   apply for a residence permit should however turn to the nearest
>   embassy of the aforementioned countries to start the proper procedure.